# Is it worth to perform android c++ softare development via MoSync?

Tags: android, c++, mobile, mosync

I had several mobile projects in which I used `MoSync`. In these projects I work mostly with c++ for *Java ME* platform. I found this toolkit nice and robust. Result was perfect, I run applications on my phone.
Now I think about android platform. I wonder if `MoSync` is right toolkit for c++ development for this platform. Will development process and result be as smooth as for *Java ME* platfrom?
Thanks!

***ADDITION***
I heard about android NDK, but as I understand, it is told that

> you should understand that the NDK will not benefit most apps

That is major reason why I avoid using it.

Comment: I have to say, I don't know anything about it, but I notice that the mosync website claims *”With the MoSync SDK, you can build mobile apps for ... Android ... using C/C++ ...”* If that’s the case, and you’re already familiar with mosync, why would you not use it?

Comment: @component I asked this question with hope that someone try this way and give his view of it. In current time I have no opportunity to test application on hardware.

Comment: A fair point. Looks like maybe that person will be you. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working with mosync to develop a app in android. before that i have experiences with other sdks like phonegap & sencha that was terrible in performance! You should write the controller of the app with javascript (in phonegap & titanium) or ruby (in rhodes). And design the UI with html & css & js, not actual native UI.

If performance is most important feature for your app, IMHO you can use mosync for android & iphone. But if you need to write another twitter plug-in, the phonegap & sencha is the best option.